# Flutter compute(): Can it be used with only one argument?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

From what I'm understanding, `compute()` takes two arguments: the function name and a variable/argument.

However, is it possible to just run a function straight off?

I have a somewhat heavy task (parsing a JSON blob) that I want to put into a separate thread so it doesn't slow down my UI:

```
  Future<void> fetchData({ref}) async {
       ....
    }
```

It is currently being used as part of a `riverpod` `ChangeNotifier`

```
await ref.read(myProvider('myId')).fetchData(ref:ref);
```

However, now in attempting to place it in a compute:

```
await compute(ref.read(myProvider('myId')).fetchData,_______);
```

What would I place in the `______` ?  I tried, null but that doesn't work.  In fact nothing seems to work and the IDE is unhappy because of:

```
The argument type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(Null)'.
```

Comment: Your heavy task *must* take a parameter and return a value (however trivial). As it's async change its return type to `Future<bool>` and return either true or false.  Change it to take exactly one (non-optional and supported) parameter - get rid of the braces round `ref` and give it a type, such as `String ref` or `int ref`. Then what you put in  `---` becomes that parameter. PS, I doubt `ref` is a supported type. Note that you may only pass relatively simple data to and from an isolate. Check the DartDoc of `compute`.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you, that makes perfect sense.  Indeed `ref` is not supported

Comment: If you send ref inside the global or static method you will get an error Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable